# Sending cookies to browser fails in Express

Tags: node.js, express, session-cookies

I am able to successfully create my cookies and I can clearly see them in my console. Now the problem is that I want to send those cookies to the browser and I am not able to do that. When I open my Chrome and go to cookies they are not present there

I have set the secure option to false and also httponly to false but it does not seem to work

```
    req.session.cart = cart;
    var cookieValue = JSON.stringify([req.session.cart],{secure:false, maxAge: 180 * 60 * 1000, httpOnly: false });       
    var cookie = req.cookies.cookieName;
        // no: set a new cookie
        res.cookie('cookieName',cookieValue);
        console.log('cookie created successfully');
        // yes, cookie was already present 
        console.log('cookie exists', cookieValue);
    res.redirect('/');
```

When I create the cookie they must appear in the browser

Comment: what happens with cookies when you `res.redirect`, instead of `res.send`? Because I'm willing to bet redirects don't also set cookie data. If you're going to redirect, then there's very little reason to set any cookies, anyway. If you're going to serve a real page, though, then you usually want to put cookie management in as a middleware function, e.g. it'll end in `next()`, not in an actual response action (like `send` or `render` or `redirect`); that'll happen in the next function in the chain.

Answer (score 0):

Like @Mike 'Pomax' Kamermans mentioned, I think this may have to do with `res.redirect`. Try adding them to your `/` route as well. Something like this:

```
// Requires cookie-parser
// https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.cookies
// https://github.com/expressjs/cookie-parser

app.post('/cart', function(req, res){
    req.session.cart = cart;
    var cookieValue = JSON.stringify([req.session.cart],{secure:false, maxAge: 180 * 60 * 1000, httpOnly: false });       
    var cookie = req.cookies.cookieName;
    if(!cookie) {
        res.cookie('cookieName',cookieValue);
        console.log('cookie created successfully');
    } else {
        console.log('cookie exists', cookieValue);
    }
    res.redirect('/');
});

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    if((typeof req.cookies == "object")&&(Object.keys(req.cookies).length>0)) {
        console.log("Cookies are present");
        // copy cookies from req to res
        for(var o=0; o<Object.keys(req.cookies).length; o++) {
            var key = Object.keys(req.cookies)[o];
            res.cookie(key,req.cookies[key]);
        }
    }
    res.status(200).send("OK");
});
```

Comment: thank you everyone for your response i am able to resolve the issue